# Error trying to enroll user and return certificates

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, ca, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to deploy `Hyperledger Composer Business Network` to `IBM Blockchain Platform BaaS` on IBM Cloud. I used the following steps:

1. Create connection.json
2. Create composer card for admin identity
3. Import the card to composer
4. Request certificates for an identity

When I am trying step 4, I am getting an error stating:

> "Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.60.181.250:31011]
>   Command failed"

I have updated the versions. And I guess the issue is due to network rules which is set in my environment. So I would request IP Range which IBM BaaS Starter and Enterprise kit consumed for Peers, Certification Authority.

Please let me know if anyone have information on IP Series.

Comment: Have you raised a ticket in the IBM Cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is on the Starter Plan?

If so, 1) ensure that you have the latest Node version (8.10.0), and npm (5.6.0). You can check your node version with

`node -v` and npm with `npm -v`

If npm or node are earlier versions, update them.

Starter Plan is currently compatible with Composer-cli v0.18.1

2) check your composer-cli version with

`composer -v`

If it is not v0.18.1, then uninstall composer:

`npm uninstall -g composer-cli`

and install v0.18.1:

`npm install -g composer-cli@0.18.1`

Now, once you create your blockchain service on IBM Cloud, when you launch your service, and ensure you are in the overview tab. Click on connection profile -> download, and rename it to `connection-profile.json` and place it in the folder where you have your .bna file. Then, open up the connection-profile.json file you just downloaded and go all the way to the bottom where you see `registrar`. Under that, you will see `enrollId` and 'enrollSecret'. Your first command then should be using that `enrollSecret` from the connection-profile. Ensure you are in the same directory as your recently downloaded connection-profile.json. The first command should be:

`composer card create -f ca.card -p connection-profile.json -u admin -s <enrollSecret>`

after that issue this command:

`composer card import -f ca.card -n ca`

and lastly:

`composer identity request --card ca --path ./credentials`

This should solve your problem. Also, I have written a full [blog](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-business-network-on-free-ibm-blockchain-starter-plan-93fafb3dd997) of me deploying a custom .bna to Starter Plan if you have any other concerns.

Comment: I have updated the versions.. And i guess the issue is due to network rules which is set in my environment. So I would request IP Range which IBM BaaS Starter and Enterprise kit consumed for Peers, Certification Authority. @Horea Porutiu

Comment: @AtulSatyajit What is the error? Also, I believe Starter Plan has updated to use Composer-Cli 0.19.4. If you want a tutorial of how to deploy business network, I have outlined the steps in this [blog](https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-business-network-on-free-ibm-blockchain-starter-plan-93fafb3dd997)

Comment: .The error was due the network rules in which I am Working. So it will be of great help if I could get information for the IP Series Used in IBM BaaS.

Comment: @AtulSatyajit Please open a ticket on IBM Cloud to get the ranges for starter Kit. IPs will not change in beta Starter plan. Not sure about enterprise plan.